# Appending (hstack) a comformable array to a matrix returns error

Tags: python, append

I am trying to `np.hstack` an array to a matrix. The array has `.shape` `(a,)`, the matrix has `.shape` `(a,b)`, with `a` and `b` integers. I get the error that dimensions do not match (`all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`). What should I do to `hstack` these conformable objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an *extra axis* to the first array using `None` or `np.newaxis`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=  np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.shape
(3,)
>>> b = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> b.shape
(3, 1)
>>> np.hstack((a[:, None], b))
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks this solves. See another option that I just found myself as alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that what you are calling array is 1-dimensional whereas the matrix is 2-dimensional.

Let's say they are called `M` and `N`. `M.shape` gives `(a,)` (being what you called "an array") and `N.shape` gives `(a,b)` (being what you called "a matrix"). If you do `M = M.reshape(a, 1)` you get a bidimensional array with the same amount of rows as `N` and `np.hstack((M, N))` should work.

P.S: All the entities you mentioned are arrays, perhaps you meant vector or 1-dimensional array for the first one.

EDIT - For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=  np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.shape
(3,)

>>> b = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
>>> b.shape
(3,1)

>>> c = np.hstack((a.reshape(3, 1), b))
>>> c
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
>>> c.shape
(3,2)
```

Comment: The first part is true, but `reshape` does not work.

Comment: Any output? What do you mean it desn't work? The function fails or inputing the reshaped array to `hstack` still gives you problems?

Comment: problem remains unchanged.

Comment: I'd like to know why has this answer been voted negative. Is it because of efficiency? I used this approach because when I started with numpy all the talk about axis confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
np.transpose(np.asmatrix(a))
```

before appending.